# Keep files updated from remote server

Tags: linux, bash

I have a server at `hostname.com/files`. Whenever a file has been uploaded I want to download it.

I was thinking of creating a script that constantly checked the `files` directory. It would check the timestamp of the files on the server and download them based on that.

Is it possible to check the files timestamp using a bash script? Are there better ways of doing this?

I could just download all the files in the server every 1 hour. Would it therefore be better to use a cron job?

Comment: Use `rsync`, it will just copy the files that are new or have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a regular interval at which you'd like to update your files, yes, a cron job is probably your best bet. Just write a script that does the checking and run that at an hourly interval.

As @Barmar commented above, `rsync` could be another option. Put something like this in the `crontab` and you should be set:

```
# min hour      day month day-of-week user command
17 *    * * *   user  rsync -av http://hostname.com/ >> rsync.log
```

would grab files from the server in that location and append the details to `rsync.log` on the 17th minute of every hour. Right now, though, I can't seem to get `rsync` to get files from a webserver.

Another option using `wget` is:

```
wget -Nrb -np -o wget.log http://hostname.com/
```

where `-N` re-downloads only files newer than the timestamp on the local version, `-b` sends 
the process to the background, `-r` recurses into directories and `-o` specifies a log file. This works from an arbitrary web server. `-np` makes sure it doesn't go up into a parent directory, effectively spidering the entire server's content.

More details, as usual, will be in the man pages of `rsync` or `wget`.